# Place SeekBar over Imageview in Android?

Tags: android

Greetings,

I have the following layout in Android. I'm trying to make it so the seekbar is displayed ontop of the image (I have some code that makes it visible and invisible(Or rather GONE).

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to position it so that the seekbar goes over the imageview, therefore allowing the imageview to take up the entire screen.

Thanks

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<.imageOverlay android:id="@+id/surface"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center" />

<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<SeekBar
 android:id="@+id/seekbar"
 android:layout_width="100px"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
 android:max="255"/>

<ImageView
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:id="@+id/surfaceimage"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
  />
```

Comment: did you close the LinearLayout and RelativeLayout tags?

Comment: Got it working witht eh below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it working with the following - I added framelayout instead of linearlayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<.imageOverlay android:id="@+id/surface"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center" />


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<ImageView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/surfaceimage"
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
  />
  <SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekbar"
android:layout_width="100px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:max="255"/>


</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what the hell is `.imageOverlay

Comment: Hi @HugoM.Zuleta - it was part of the SDK back in Android 1.6. I haven't programmed any android since, so I'm guessing by your response its no longer there :-) p.s The question is 7 years old.

Comment: makes sense. Thanks for the reply.